# Postgres local volumes gets deleted when using golang air

Tags: docker, go

I am getting the `failed to initialize` error whenever I start up my docker container service.

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    container_name: api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: local.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
      - "40000:40000"
    security_opt:
      - "seccomp:unconfined"
    cap_add:
      - SYS_PTRACE
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      PORT: 9090
      DB_CONN: "postgres://admin:pass@db:5432/test?sslmode=disable"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:         
      POSTGRES_USER: "admin"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "pass"
      POSTGRES_DB: "test"
      TZ: "UTC"
      PGTZ: "UTC"
    volumes:
      - ./tmp:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

I am using `air` for live reload, please find the `air.toml` file

```
root="."
tmp_dir="tmp"

[build]
cmd="go build -gcflags=\"all=-N -l\" -o ./bin/main ."
bin="/app/bin"
full_bin="/app/bin/main"
log="air_errors.log"
include_ext=["go", "yaml"]
exclude_dir=["tmp"]
delay=1000

[log]
time=true


[misc]
clean_on_exit=true




func main() {
    Instance, err = gorm.Open(postgres.Open(conn), &gorm.Config{
            Logger: logger.New(
                log.New(os.Stdout, "", log.LstdFlags), logger.Config{
                    LogLevel: logger.Info,
                    Colorful: true,
                }),
        })
        if err != nil {
            panic("Cannot connect to DB" + err.Error())
        }
    }
```

Intially when the containers are up, the volumes are there, a `tmp`
folder gets generated in the local machine, but when we run `docker compose down`  the `tmp` folder gets deleted, it doesn't gets deleted if the air live reloads the code.

The volumes persists if air package  is removed and golang runs normally